# Get stucked in new MockUp Call

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jmockit

```
@Test
public void testMockUp() {
    try {
        System.out.println("abcdefg");
        new MockUp<TransactionAlert>() {
            @Mock(invocations = 1)
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("i am runing");
            }
        };
        System.out.println("hijklmn");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code above get stuck in the new MockUp<> statement.In the console, i can only see the first output statement "abcdefg" rather than "hijklmn".

And i also try to set break and use the debugger to trace how the program run.Turns out after invoke the MockUp class static initialization, the program seems to be stuck.No Expception throw, no stop, just hang in there.

Thanks for your help!

=====updated after try review the jmockit documentation=================
It points out that i should

"""
When using JUnit 4.5+, verify that jmockit.jar (or the equivalent Maven dependency) appears before JUnit in the classpath. Alternatively, annotate test classes with @RunWith(JMockit.class). 
"""

Finally, i fix it by using @RunWith.

But i still have two question.

1.What does the "verify that jmockit.jar (or the equivalent Maven dependency) appears before JUnit in the classpath" statement means? ---> i have to make jmockit.jar before JUnit in the classpath? how can i do that? by specially configure the classpath?

2.Why it went wrong (but not throw exception) when i haven't use @RunWith.

Thanks again!

Comment: i think the problem is on the MockUp statement.Because i try deleting the MockUp statement and everythings seems to be fine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with jmockit, but that message indicates they are using Class names that are equal to names of classes in junit. The one that's "on top" in the classpath gets found first and is used, the other one ignored.

Comment: The @runWith-solution is certainly preferrable to manually adjusting the build path, as it is more explicit.

Comment: You should consider posting your solution as an answer instead of as part of the question. You can then mark it as the correct answer after waiting a day to see if someone else wants to add a more complete answer.